# Calling a method from an object at the START of a Queue

Tags: java, object, methods, queue, call

Within my Driver class:

```
for (systemClock = 0; systemClock < 200; systemClock = (systemClock + 1)){
        if(((inputQueue.query()).arrivalTime()) == systemClock)
            System.out.println(((inputQueue.remove()).removalTime()));
    }
```

Within a Job class:

```
public int arrivalTime()
{
    return arrivalTime;
}
```

My problem is within the second line of code.

```
if(((inputQueue.query()).arrivalTime()) == systemClock)
```

In class we made a basic `QueueObject`, with a method `query()` which returns the object found at the FRONT of the queue. Each object is a job, which has various variables and methods within them (all that matters in this case is the "Arrival Time" of this object). I'm trying to get this line of code to return the object, and call the `arrivalTime()` method / find out the arrival time from this specific object.

Edit: I'm getting a compile error "cannot find symbol - method arrivalTime()"

Solution Edit:
Sorry for the confusion / bad post guys. I apologize. Here is the solution I got to work. I had to cast the object being pulled off the queue as a Job object.

```
if((((Job)inputQueue.query()).arrivalTime()) == systemClock)
```

Comment: Uh... What's your question then?

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is with the code you posted. You say "My problem is within the second line of code" - what "problem"? You also haven't asked a question.

Comment: shoot my bad! The problem is I'm getting an error on compile. It highlights this line and says it cannot find the symbol, "method arrivalTime()"

Comment: is the method `arrivalTime()` marked as private? If it is, it should be public. And which is the type returned by the method? It must have the same type as `systemClock`, and remember you can only use `==` with numbers (`int`, `long`, `double`,...). If the type is not comparable with `==`  you'll need to create a `compareTo()` or `equals()` method.

Comment: I've included the arrival time method found inside the job object above. Both are simple ints, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the extra parenthesis,and (just in case), use an inequality:

```
if (inputQueue.query().arrivalTime() >= systemClock) {
    // ...
}
```

I'm assuming that your `query()` method returns a `Job` object (if it doesn't, then there's a problem with your `Queue` design).

---

So, your problem is that the symbol is not found.

Some tips:

1. is the method arrivalTime() marked as private? If it is, it should be public.
2. Which is the type returned by the method? It must have the same type as systemClock, and remember you can only use == with numbers (int, long, double,...). If the type is not comparable with == you'll need to create a compareTo() or equals() method

Comment: The query method works exactly as it should. I need it to only return the method if the arrival time is EQAUL TO (==) the system clock. So this wouldn't work I think.

Comment: @StephenGilardi That happens when you don't ask the **full** question

Comment: I apologize. I updated the original question with my problem.

Comment: Yes, the method is public and both variables are ints.

Comment: Here, let me rephrase the question really quick to help simplify my problem. Let's say we had an array filled with Student objects. How would I remove a Student from the array, and use a getAge method on it?

Comment: @StephenGilardi Please post the code of `Job` (at least, the `arrivalTime()`) method, and the code of your `Queue`

Comment: I've emailed my professor, and he told me that the object I'm pulling out of the Queue must be cast into a job object before I can access it.

I updated the solution I found in the original post. Thank you for your help.